# Using a headless browser with Heroku Rails Unicorn stack

Tags: heroku, phantomjs, headless-browser

I have seen posts that you can change the build on Heroku, to use PhantomJS with the Cedar stack, but is it possible to run a headless browser on the unicorn stack?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, and someone already wrote a buildpack for including PhantomJS (the internet and open source are amazing).

If you want to run headless PhantomJS on a Heroku dyno, you will need to:

- Switch to Heroku multi-buildpack: https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi
- Setup Ruby buildpack for your app: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
- Setup PhantomJS buildpack for your needs: https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs

The multi buildpack must be configured as the official Heroku buildpack.  You then need to add the other two buildpack URLs to the `.buildpacks` file.  There are additional details for configuring each buildpack at the links above.

Using this, you should be able to deploy your Rails app, run your PhantomJS code/tests, all on a single dyno headlessly.

Comment: Just to be clear, will I be able to run both my app, and PhantomJS on a single Dyno, or does it need a Dyno for each?

Comment: The multi-buildpack configuration above will prepare the code needed to run them both (Ruby, bundler, PhantomJS, etc) on a single dyno. If you're planning to execute phantomJS code within your app code, that will work.

Comment: Hmm it seems like I am getting timeouts when trying to use Watir with PhantomJS. Don't know if it is due to Watir or PhantomJS.